# [Android][RecyclerView] Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a simple Android application following [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) tutorial. I am getting compile error on the *onBindViewHolder* method with this message:

*error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype*

Here is my code:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CryptogramPairingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public CryptogramPairingAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.pair_crypto_recyclerview, parent, false);
        CryptogramPairingAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

I am confused as the code is nearly identical (except for modified name) to the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you change your `ViewHolder` to be named something other than `ViewHolder`, as it is conflicting with `ViewHolder` and is simply going to cause you confusion in distinguishing `ViewHolder` from `ViewHolder`.

<sub>(and [I complained to Google about this lousy practice in their example](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111238026))</sub>

Given the code in its current state, change:

```
public class CryptogramPairingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
```

to:

```
public class CryptogramPairingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CryptogramPairingAdapter.ViewHolder>
```

Comment: Thanks! This fix compiles the code now. What does <,> do in this case? Sorry, I am quite new to OOP.

Comment: @b1gtuna: That is not so much an OOP thing as a Java thing. This pertains to Java generics. For example, `ArrayList` can hold any sort of object, which makes data typing difficult. Fortunately, `ArrayList` supports generics, so we can declare `ArrayList<Animal>` and say that we have a list that holds `Animal` objects. Similarly, here, we are saying that we are creating a `RecyclerView.Adapter` whose items are represented in the form of `CryptogramPairingAdapter.ViewHolder` objects, when we use `RecyclerView.Adapter<CryptogramPairingAdapter.ViewHolder>`.

Comment: @b1gtuna: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java or your favorite book on Java programming for more on generics.